# Can topologically non-trivial edge states exist without an energy gap?

Tags: electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators, density-functional-theory

I am relatively new to the field of topological materials, and I came across a paper that claims that they found topologically non-trivial states in a material. Basically, the authors found a type-I Dirac cone in the electronic band structure and carried out analysis of non-triviality of these states. The code they used confirmed that the states are indeed non-trivial. One thing that I don't understand is that the authors computed the electronic band structure for that material with and without including spin-orbit coupling and in both cases there was no gap (the Dirac cone remained intact). If there is no gap to begin with, how can there be topologically protected edge states ? The idea, as I understand it, is that the edge states close the gap.

Thank you for your time.